Spring Boot Virtual Threads pinning with ActiveMQ Classic
I am on Spring Boot 3.2.5 with virtual threads enabled and connecting to an external ActiveMQ Classic broker using the ActiveMQ 5.18.4 client. I am using the JmsTemplate sendAndReceive() method to send a message on a request queue and get back the response from a response queue with a @JmsListener. Whenever I send a message, I get a thread pinning warning as follows:
2024-05-18 15:06:39.916  INFO 29496 --- [omcat-handler-5] c.b.i.m.impl.OFSActiveMQProducer         : Producer: Sending message to queue Q.ENQ.IN.DEV with correlationID 85ea6e1a-56fd-4e94-b822-f5c44e363408
Thread[#52,ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1,5,CarrierThreads]
    org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession.send(ActiveMQSession.java:2045) <== monitors:1
2024-05-18 15:06:40.047  INFO 29496 --- [ntContainer#0-1] c.b.iraq.messaging.EnqActiveMQConsumer   : Enq Consumer: Received message from queue Q.ENQ.OUT.DEV with Id: 85ea6e1a-56fd-4e94-b822-f5c44e363408 
2024-05-18 15:06:40.253  INFO 29496 --- [omcat-handler-5] c.b.i.m.impl.OFSActiveMQProducer         : Producer: Successfully received message from consumer for Q.ENQ.IN.DEV with ID: 85ea6e1a-56fd-4e94-b822-f5c44e363408

I checked the documentation, but I couldn't find anything stating if ActiveMQ supports virtual threads or not. Can anyone please advise if there is a way to remedy the pinning, or if it's okay to allow this pinning when sending a JMS message.


the stacktrace seems edited and is this from -Djdk.tracePinnedThreads=full?
The line of code from the client where this hints to  a synchronised function this.connection.syncSendPacket(msg, onComplete);
Some work in favor of supporting virtual thread can be found here.


Thank you for the info Naman! The stack trace is from -Djdk.tracePinnedThreads=short. As for the stack trace I only removed the application name block [ApplicationName], but I was unaware of the lack of support for virtual threads.

I do understand the application name removal, but the reason I could determine it to have been edited was the thread name e.g. omcat-handler-5 should have been tomcat and why not enable full trace and update the question with it?
